# swiftのWebViewで指定箇所から表示させる方法は？

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

swiftのWebViewで指定箇所から表示させる方法は？ 
下の写真の赤のライン以下を検索結果として表示したいんですが、コードがわかりません。 
よろしくお願いします 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

方法としては二通りあると思います。
一つは表示する位置を固定して赤線から上の部分を見えなくする方法です、こちらはちょっとわかりませんでした。

二つ目は、赤線から上の部分を消してしまう方法です。

swift側からjavascriptを実行して、htmlを操作しページのソースコードを書き換えればいいと思います。

ですが、これにはhtmlとjavascriptの知識が若干必要になると思います。